# Change of Network Interface using Metrics

Tags: networking, network-interface, metric

I want to achieve dynamic interface change between eth0 and wlan0, one solution I am looking into is to change interface metric. Different than [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/630981/how-do-i-configure-a-linux-machine-to-ignore-wifi-when-connected-via-lan), I don't want to make any change to `/etc/networking/interfaces`, so I used [`ifmetric`](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/ifmetric/)to change interface metrics.

```
$ netstat -ren
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1000   0        0 wlan0
$ sudo ifmetric eth0 1000
$ sudo ifmetric wlan0 0
$ netstat -ren
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1000   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

But I don't know how to put this metric to effect, i.e. how to refresh the routing table to reflect metric and let wlan0 become the primary interface?